# How to set the first 3 columns of dataGridView readOnly to true

Tags: c#, datagridview, readonly

I have a dataGridView in which some data are retrived from database in just first three columns and the forth column is checkBoxColumn which I want to make it checkable ,but when I set the property ReadOnly to my dataGridView it does not allow me to check the checkBoxColumn !!
How can I solve this problem?
With my regards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can add unbound column by clicking on the data grid view tasks.

Then set the below properties.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Then add your column details and assign the data property for each column by clicking on Edit column or add column . also set readonly property for each column to true.

Add Checkbox as last column and set ReadOnly false.

Comment: I'm galad sir that you made me remind this , I don't know how I missed up this trick that I've read about many times.. Thanks